# What is the probability of pulling out learnt question?

Tags: probability

I found this math problem but couldn't find solution:

There are 20 possible subjects, but you only had time to prepare for 15. If two subjects are given, what chances do you have to be familiar with both?

Can somebody please explain how to solve this kind of probability problem and share some resources for practicing?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hi there, your question as currently phrased is likely to attract close votes and downvotes. To avoid this and also to get the best answers suited to your understanding, I suggest checking [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution for your problem. 
Let the event that both the subjects belong to the set of prepared subjects be *E*.
The number of ways this can occur is <sub>15</sub>C<sub>2</sub> 
Let the total number of ways in which 2 subjects can be chosen from 20 subjects be *S*. The number of ways in which this can happen is <sub>20</sub>C<sub>2</sub>.
So, the solution to your question can be calculated using the formula 
$Probability = \frac{n(E)}{n(S)} = \frac{_{15}C_{2}}{_{20}C_2} = \frac{105}{190}$.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think i get it.